# Can sorting be handled in UI code instead of OData call with an $orderby in a List Report SAP Fiori app?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have developed a List Report application. Sorting capability is required in the table columns. When I try to trigger the sort option for any of the columns, OData service is called with a $orderby parameter. $orderby is not yet handled in the backend, and thus the OData call just returns the data in the default sequence. I wanted to know if I can avoid the OData call and instead sort the already fetched data?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `operationMode` property on the OData model to `client` and it will do the sorting & filtering in the client instead of performing an `$orderby` request on the server.

Note the comments on the [operationModel](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.OperationMode%23properties) option:

> Operations are executed on the client. This only works if all entries
> are loaded on the client. The initial request fetches the complete
> collection, filtering and sorting does not trigger further requests.